# Why my scroll view does not scroll to the bottom when adding two sentences consecutively?

Tags: scrollview, scrollbar, unity-game-engine

I created a scroll window like this, hoping it will auto scroll to the bottom when text continuously come:

```
public class LogWindow : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Text logText;
    Queue<string> textQueue = new Queue<string>();
    public ScrollRect scrollRect;
    public Scrollbar scrollbar;

    void RefreshText()
    {
        string buffer = "";
        foreach(string text in textQueue)
        {
            buffer += text;
            buffer += '\n';
        }

        logText.text = buffer;
        scrollRect.verticalNormalizedPosition = 0.0f;
        scrollbar.value = 0.0f;
    }

    public void Log(string text, string color = "white")
    {
        text = String.Format("<color={0}>{1}</color>", color, text);
        textQueue.Enqueue(text);
        RefreshText();
    }
}
```

It works fine when I call `RefreshText` once at a time. But when I do this:

```
Log("something 1");
Log("something 2");
```

I see that the log window is only scrolled down so that "something 1" is shown. I have to drag it manually to see "something 2".

My settings on the Text is:

[image: Text settings]

I suppose there is something wrong in `RefreshText`. Can anyone tell me where did I go wrong?

Thank you!

Comment: Doesn't scrollRect.verticalNormalizedPosition = 0.0f; reset the pos to the top?

Comment: @Absinthe I don't think so, the Unity official document said "The vertical scroll position as a value between 0 and 1, with 0 being at the bottom."